# Why does open OpenLDAP require a cn=username?

Tags: c#, openldap

I'm connecting to OpenLDAP with C#, and when I pass in my username and password, I have to pass them into my LdapConnection object as cn=Username, Password. If I just pass in username and password my call to Bind fails. Why do I have to do that? Is something misconfigured on my OpenLDAP server?

Comment: The `CN=` prefix is part of the LDAP specs - it's short for *Common Name* - and no, there's nothing misconfigured - that's just the way LDAP identifies objects (like users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a byproduct of the implementation. Novell's eDirectory solution takes a very similar approach, and I use the same `Novell.Directory.Ldap` code to handle bind requests to both eDirectory and OpenLDAP. Now obviously, the users themselves shouldn't have to enter their entire CN when authorizing - we can just issue a search for them, based of thier UID :

```
//Setup the initial bind for the admin user
var lc = new LdapConnection();
lc.SecureSocketLayer = SSL;
lc.UserDefinedServerCertValidationDelegate += delegate { return true; };
lc.Connect(ServerName, Port);
lc.Constraints.TimeLimit = Timeout;
lc.Bind(AdminUsername, AdminPassword);
```

Now I just filter for the user, and bind using their distinguished name, or full container name (CN) :

```
//Ex. (uid=jsmith)
string filter = config.LdapAuth.LdapFilter.Replace("{{uid}}", username);

//Find the user we're trying to authorize
var lsc = lc.Search(config.LdapAuth.LdapDomain, LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB, filter, null, false);

if (lsc.hasMore())
{
    LdapEntry nextEntry = lsc.next();

    //Check the Entries DN so we can properly bind 
    lc.Bind(nextEntry.DN, Password);
}
```

This was the most widely used approach I could find, and it's worked quite well so far.